# How to import Azure devops solution data into Power BI Desktop

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi-desktop

My goal is to import work items from an Azure devops solution into my local Power BI Desktop. Following links such as [this demo link](https://www.jie-tao.com/simple-way-to-create-gantt-chart-for-azure-devops-through-power-bi/) and [this product link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops), I'm currently blocked on importing the data. The UI error is:
[image]
I do have contributor access to the repo - I have done many pull requests - and the URL is (obfuscated): [https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION_NAME}/Solutions/_git/{PROJECT_NAME}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BORGANIZATION_NAME%7D/Solutions/_git/%7BPROJECT_NAME%7D). Perhaps there is an issue that it is a "solution"?

The product link above shows this example URL: http://{ORGANIZATION_NAME}/AzureDevOpsServer/fabrikam-collection/{PROJECT_NAME}/Device. The examples shown in the hover help in Power BI Desktop itself shows these examples:
[image] and [image]

Possibly I'll consider writing a query in Azure DevOps, exporting the results, importing that as a file into PBI Desktop, and transforming as needed; however, I'd much prefer to make use of this built-in import mechanism.

Comment: I might just answer and close my own question. Playing around with things a bit more, there appears to be no such thing as a "solution"; rather, it appears that my team is using "Solutions" as the name of the project itself. Using that, I can, in fact, import the data. It's importing far more data than I want, but at least it does appear to be working. Given the sheer volume, I might end up writing a query to dump only the relevant data and transform it as needed later. I'll keep this open for a bit, in case someone happens to know a way to just import the specific repo I'm interested in.

Comment: To be a bit more concrete, using my URL from the top - extracting the organization name and project name from the URL is what works for me, but I can't filter it further using the repo, so now I'm going to focus on that (a bit different than the original posting):  https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION_NAME}/{PROJECT_NAME}/_git/{REPO_NAME}.

Comment: very relevant related link - about deriving organization and project name from URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops#q-how-do-i-resolve-the-project-x-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions-to-access-it-error

Comment: The solution to filter the data by using an Analytics View - see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-are-analytics-views?view=azure-devops. The basic flow is: Azure DevOps > Analytics View > Power BI Data Connector > Power BI Desktop

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the original error was fixed by properly using the 'organization' and 'project' from the URL - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops#q-how-do-i-resolve-the-project-x-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions-to-access-it-error) in particular. The follow-up question was achieved by using [Analytics Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-are-analytics-views?view=azure-devops).